# Git: didn't commit branch before checking out a new one

Tags: git, git-branch

I was doing some work on a branch, then checked out a new branch without committing the old one. Once on the new branch, I deleted / added a bunch of stuff, then committed the changes. Now when I go back to the original branch, it's missing a lot of stuff that was added to it following the last commit to that branch. Argghhh!

Is there any way to get that branch back to the way it was before I checked out the new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, content you never showed Git directly, i.e. commited or at least staged, is gone forever once you remove it. However, when you switched to the new one, your changes should have been carried over, so unless you completely removed the changes there, it should be contained in the commits over there.

Comment: Yes, the changes have been carried over but not all of them. Thanx.